# Github actions: Using mysql service throws access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: github, github-actions

Error, access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
I am trying to use the mysql service in Github Actions, but to no luck. I get the following error

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My job is the following:

```
test:
  name: Test
  needs: install
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      ports:
        - '8888:3306'
      env:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
        MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: actions/setup-node@master
      with:
        node-version: '10.x'
    - run: mysql --port 8888 -u root -prootpass -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;'
```

I cant seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated. The pull request for my repository for the test setup can be found here: https://github.com/morsby/medmcq/pull/399

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL instance is ready to accept logins before your step runs?

Comment: hi, im having a similar issue, what do you mean by ready to accept logins?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I spent some time trying different things to get this to work. I found a solution, but quite honestly, I'm not sure *why* it works. I simply added `-h 127.0.0.1` to the mysql command.

I also added the health check flags to `options` to make sure the service is able to accept requests.

This is a working workflow:

```
name: CI
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test
        ports:
            - '8888:3306'
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - run: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port 8888 -u root -ppassword -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;'
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I've seen those options around on forums, but I've not understood why they were included until now. You explanation is excellent. Thank you! It is all working now. It likely works because the health checks make sure to wait for the next step, while the mysql service is starting.

Comment: @ThomasJensen Even with the healthchecks, if you remove the `-h 127.0.0.1` it throws an access denied error. I think that flag is the key to making this work.

Comment: This is required because of a weird historical idiosyncrasy in MySQL, where it takes `localhost` (the default) to mean a local UNIX socket connection, while `127.0.0.1` is a TCP/IP connection.